# how to get attack animation to work in lua?

Tags: animation, lua, defold

```
local move_acceleration = 3500
-- acceleration factor to use when air-borne
local air_acceleration_factor = 0.8
-- max speed right/left
local max_speed = 450
-- gravity pulling the player down in pixel units
local gravity = -1000
-- take-off speed when jumping in pixel units
local jump_takeoff_speed = 350
-- time within a double tap must occur to be considered a jump (only used for mouse/touch controls)
local touch_jump_timeout = 0.2

-- pre-hashing ids improves performance
local msg_contact_point_response = hash("contact_point_response")
local msg_animation_done = hash("animation_done")
local group_obstacle = hash("wall/ground")
local input_left = hash("Left")
local input_right = hash("Right")
local input_jump = hash("Jump")
local input_touch = hash("touch")
local anim_run = hash("Run")
local anim_idle = hash("Idle")
local anim_jump = hash("Jump")
local anim_fall = hash("Fall")
local anim_death = hash("Death")
local anim_attack = hash("Attack")

function init(self)
    -- this lets us handle input in this script
    msg.post(".", "acquire_input_focus")

    -- initial player velocity
    self.velocity = vmath.vector3(0, 0, 0)
    -- support variable to keep track of collisions and separation
    self.correction = vmath.vector3()
    -- if the player stands on ground or not
    self.ground_contact = false
    -- movement input in the range [-1,1]
    self.move_input = 0
    -- the currently playing animation
    self.anim = nil
    -- timer that controls the jump-window when using mouse/touch
    self.touch_jump_timer = 0
end

local function play_animation(self, anim)
    -- only play animations which are not already playing
    if self.anim ~= anim then
        -- tell the sprite to play the animation
        sprite.play_flipbook("#player", anim)
        -- remember which animation is playing
        self.anim = anim
    end
end

local function update_animations(self)
    -- make sure the player character faces the right way
    sprite.set_hflip("#player", self.move_input < 0)
    -- make sure the right animation is playing
    if self.ground_contact then
        if self.velocity.x == 0 then
            play_animation(self, anim_idle)
        else
            play_animation(self, anim_run)
        end
    else
        if self.velocity.y > 0 then
            play_animation(self, anim_jump)
        else
            play_animation(self, anim_fall)
        end
    end
end



function update(self, dt)
    -- determine the target speed based on input
    local target_speed = self.move_input * max_speed
    -- calculate the difference between our current speed and the target speed
    local speed_diff = target_speed - self.velocity.x
    -- the complete acceleration to integrate over this frame
    local acceleration = vmath.vector3(0, gravity, 0)
    if speed_diff ~= 0 then
        -- set the acceleration to work in the direction of the difference
        if speed_diff < 0 then
            acceleration.x = -move_acceleration
        else
            acceleration.x = move_acceleration
        end
        -- decrease the acceleration when air-borne to give a slower feel
        if not self.ground_contact then
            acceleration.x = air_acceleration_factor * acceleration.x
        end
    end
    -- calculate the velocity change this frame (dv is short for delta-velocity)
    local dv = acceleration * dt
    -- check if dv exceeds the intended speed difference, clamp it in that case
    if math.abs(dv.x) > math.abs(speed_diff) then
        dv.x = speed_diff
    end
    -- save the current velocity for later use
    -- (self.velocity, which right now is the velocity used the previous frame)
    local v0 = self.velocity
    -- calculate the new velocity by adding the velocity change
    self.velocity = self.velocity + dv
    -- calculate the translation this frame by integrating the velocity
    local dp = (v0 + self.velocity) * dt * 0.5
    -- apply it to the player character
    go.set_position(go.get_position() + dp)

    -- update the jump timer
    if self.touch_jump_timer > 0 then
        self.touch_jump_timer = self.touch_jump_timer - dt
    end

    update_animations(self)

    -- reset volatile state
    self.correction = vmath.vector3()
    self.move_input = 0
    self.ground_contact = false

end

local function handle_obstacle_contact(self, normal, distance)
    -- project the correction vector onto the contact normal
    -- (the correction vector is the 0-vector for the first contact point)
    local proj = vmath.dot(self.correction, normal)
    -- calculate the compensation we need to make for this contact point
    local comp = (distance - proj) * normal
    -- add it to the correction vector
    self.correction = self.correction + comp
    -- apply the compensation to the player character
    go.set_position(go.get_position() + comp)
    -- check if the normal points enough up to consider the player standing on the ground
    -- (0.7 is roughly equal to 45 degrees deviation from pure vertical direction)
    if normal.y > 0.7 then
        self.ground_contact = true
    end
    -- project the velocity onto the normal
    proj = vmath.dot(self.velocity, normal)
    -- if the projection is negative, it means that some of the velocity points towards the contact point
    if proj < 0 then
        -- remove that component in that case
        self.velocity = self.velocity - proj * normal
    end
end

function on_message(self, message_id, message, sender)
    -- check if we received a contact point message
    if message_id == msg_contact_point_response then
        -- check that the object is something we consider an obstacle
        if message.group == group_obstacle then
            handle_obstacle_contact(self, message.normal, message.distance)
        end
    end
end

local function jump(self)
    -- only allow jump from ground
    -- (extend this with a counter to do things like double-jumps)
    if self.ground_contact then
        -- set take-off speed
        self.velocity.y = jump_takeoff_speed
        -- play animation
        play_animation(self, anim_jump)
    end
end

local function abort_jump(self)
    -- cut the jump short if we are still going up
    if self.velocity.y > 0 then
        -- scale down the upwards speed
        self.velocity.y = self.velocity.y * 0.5
    end
end

function on_input(self, action_id, action)
    if action_id == input_left then
        self.move_input = -action.value
    elseif action_id == input_right then
        self.move_input = action.value
    elseif action_id == input_jump then
        if action.pressed then
            jump(self)
        elseif action.released then
            abort_jump(self)
        end
    elseif action_id == input_touch then
        -- move towards the touch-point
        local diff = action.x - go.get_position().x
        -- only give input when far away (more than 10 pixels)
        if math.abs(diff) > 10 then
            -- slow down when less than 100 pixels away
            self.move_input = diff / 100
            -- clamp input to [-1,1]
            self.move_input = math.min(1, math.max(-1, self.move_input))
        end
        if action.released then
            -- start timing the last release to see if we are about to jump
            self.touch_jump_timer = touch_jump_timeout
        elseif action.pressed then
            -- jump on double tap
            if self.touch_jump_timer > 0 then
                jump(self)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

this is movement, animation and collision code ive gotten from the defold website however i want to add an animation but i dont understand why it doesn't work ive tried various solutions and ways to get the attack animation to work but i couldn't figure it out, all animation is under the correct names

Comment: That's way more code than anybody is going to read through when you don't even have an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

`contact_point_response` message is sent when one of the colliding objects is dynamic or kinematic. If you selected `trigger` colliding object, it doesn't send `contact_point_response` message. You should check what kind of colliding object used. You can find detail in this [document](https://defold.com/manuals/physics-messages/).

Comment: Please add the relevant code so that the answer still has meaning if the link breaks.